# Pass the array of duration in hh:mm:ss format in the URL

Tags: url

I have a requirement to pass the array of duration in hh:mm:ss format in the URL. Do you recommend serializing it vs decoding it while sending it in the URL. This has to be passed in the GET URL call hence a JSON POST body cannot be constructed. What are some of the things that need to be considered while taking care of this?

Comment: URL encode whatever string you send, and then you can put in anything you want. It sounds like the formatting requirement is something separate/work-defined, but the answers the same as when you google anything else for it: use some formatter, parse your duration (or convert if numeric and necessary), and then format it as desired.